# How do I reference current scope?

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, alias

I frequently get column name clashes, like the following artificial example:

```sql
with
  weekdays('name') as (
    values
      ('Monday')
    , ('Tuesday')
    , ('Wednesday')
    , ('Thursday')
    , ('Friday')
    , ('Saturday')
    , ('Sunday')
  )
select
  substr("name",1,3) as "name"
from weekdays

where 1==1
and "name" == 'Monday'
-- how do I reference current scope's name, where "name" == 'Mon'?
```

In *bash* it would be:

```sql
and ./"name" == 'Monday'
```

to reference current scope's `name` instead of first `name` from the `$PATH`.

Is there a way to reference current scope in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL does not allow aliases of derived columns to be used in the `WHERE` clause, because `SELECT` is processed after `WHERE`.

SQLite allows it (probably by replacing the alias in the `WHERE` clause with its respective expression), but when there is a name conflict with a column of the participating tables/ctes the aliased column is shadowed by the existing column.

This means that in your case you can't refer directly to the aliased column.
Instead repeat the expression:

```
and substr("name",1,3) = 'Mon'
```

Or, use a subquery:

```
select *
from (
  select
    substr("name",1,3) as "name"
  from weekdays
)
where 1=1
and "name" = 'Mon'
```

Or, better, use a different non-conflicting alias.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LSlF87iD).